# Toolbar from MasterDetailPage

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

How can I get navigation back button event if I have MasterDetailPage?

Toolbar toolbar = FindViewById(Resource.Id.toolbar) return *null*

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.navigationpage.onbackbuttonpressed?view=xamarin-forms

Comment: Thanks for updating question. You should use `Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar` , then it will be not null.

Answer (score 0):

If want to get event of the hardware back button, you can use **[OnBackButtonPressed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.navigationpage.onbackbuttonpressed?view=xamarin-forms)** method in ContentPage to get navigation back button event as follow:

```
protected override bool OnBackButtonPressed()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Press back button.");
    return base.OnBackButtonPressed();
}
```

> Event that is raised when the hardware back button is pressed. This event is not raised on iOS.

=====================================Update==================================

Else if want to get back event from ToolBar , you should use `Android.Support.V7.Widget` for `Toolbar`.

[image]

In **Acitivity** OnCreate:

```
Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = this.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Override `OnOptionsItemSelected` method :

```
public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
{
    if(item.ItemId == Android.Resource.Id.Home)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Here is back button event.");
    }
    return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: If I using MasterDetailPage then Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar is null

Comment: @KsenijaPanovskaya Okey , got it. I will check it .

Comment: @KsenijaPanovskaya Glad be helpful , thanks for marking in advance :)